# Multithreading threads of functionB does not start until thread of function A finish, but threads of functionA do Not wait for functionB

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to set up multithreading of two functions. The execution of function B is dependent on function A finishing, so I want to wait until all the threads of function A are finished before running a thread of function B. But function A does not depend on function B, so while a thread of function B is running, I want to start running threads of function A. In this case, function B only needs 1 thread, but function A can have multiple.

Here is a code example of my best attempt. The code below creates a list in `functionB` of length 20, in 20 iteration with `functionB`. And within each of those 20 iterations, `functionA` goes through 200 iterations to make it's own temporary list `firstList`, which `functionB` uses to create a single item in `secondList`

Those 200 iterations of `functionA` can have multiple workers. `functionB` can only have one at a time. Within an iteration of `k`, `functionB` needs to wait until all 200 iterations of `functionA` is completed. But at iteration `k+1` , `functionA` should continue with it's next iterations and Not wait for the iteration of `functionB` at iteration `k`.

```
import threading

maxthreads = 4 
sema1 = threading.Semaphore(value=maxthreads)

maxthreads = 1 
sema2 = threading.Semaphore(value=maxthreads)


def functionA( i ):
    sema1.acquire()
    firstList.append( i*2 )
    sema1.release()

def functionB( j ):
    sema2.acquire()
    secondList.append( j + sum(firstList) )
    sema2.release()

secondList = []
for k in range(20):

    firstList = []

    for n in range(0, 200): 
        thread = threading.Thread(target=functionA,args=(n, ))
        thread.start()

    thread = threading.Thread(target=functionB,args=(m, ))
    thread.start()
```

How do I set up the threading such that the `functionB` function does not run until all the `n` iteration threads from `FirstOne` are completed, for each iteration of `k`, 
but also that the `functionA` threads will proceed in their iterations of `n` for the next iteration of `k+1`,  even if the single thread that is occupying `functionB` at `k` has not been completed? Since it's not necessarily for `functionB` at iteration `k` to finish, in order for threads of `functionA` at iteration `k+1` to start their tasks.

Also note, `functionB` can only have one thread running at a time, where as  `functionA` can have multiple threads.

Edit:

Dan D. posted a solution below which prevents both functions A and B from running until the other is finished, but I only need to prevent B from running until A is finished, A can run without B, I came up with this solution based on Dan D's solution

```
a_threads = []
secondList = []
for k in range(20):

    firstList = []

    for n in range(0, 200): 
        thread = threading.Thread(target=functionA,args=(n, ))
        thread.start()
        a_threads.append(thread)

    for thread in a_threads:
        thread.join()

    a_threads = []    

    thread = threading.Thread(target=functionB,args=(m, ))
    thread.start()
    a_threads.append(thread)
```

so I do not do thread join at the end of the thread of function b starting, but I append it to a_threads. After a_threads are joined at the end of calling all the function b threads, I create a new empty a_threads list.

Would this be a working solution to my requirements?

Answer (score 0):

To do that you join all the A threads before starting the B thread. And then join the B thread so that the next A threads aren't started until it ends.

```
secondList = []
for k in range(20):

    firstList = []

    a_threads = []
    for n in range(0, 200): 
        thread = threading.Thread(target=functionA,args=(n, ))
        thread.start()
        a_threads.append(thread)

    for thread in a_threads:
        thread.join()

    thread = threading.Thread(target=functionB,args=(m, ))
    thread.start()
    thread.join()
```

To allow the A threads to start before the B thread has finished that one shifts the join around.

```
secondList = []

b_thread = None
for k in range(20):

    firstList = []

    a_threads = []
    for n in range(0, 200): 
        thread = threading.Thread(target=functionA,args=(n, ))
        thread.start()
        a_threads.append(thread)

    for thread in a_threads:
        thread.join()

    if b_thread is not None:
       b_thread.join()

    thread = threading.Thread(target=functionB,args=(m, ))
    thread.start()
    b_thread = thread

if b_thread is not None:
   b_thread.join()
```

Comment: 'And then join the B thread so that the next A threads aren't started until it ends.' in my case I'll need the A threads to start before the previous B is finishing its thread. Only B should wait until A is finished, but A should Not wait until B is finished.

Comment: from looking at the documentation of https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html it says 'Other threads can call a thread’s join() method. This blocks the calling thread until the thread whose join() method is called is terminated.'  So it looks like all I have to do is Not call `thread.join()` after I call my `functionB` thread ?